# Invalid signatures and packages authentication issue

Tags: debian, linux-mint, apt

I'm using LMDE 201303 and i have two issues which i need to resolve as soon as possible.

I need to install certain libraries: libopus0 libopus0
The apt-get install yells the following message:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
libopus0 libopus0
```

Second issue is that once i want to do apt-get update i get the following message:

```
W: GPG error: http://packages.linuxmint.com debian Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 Clement Lefebvre (Linux Mint Package Repository v1) <root@linuxmint.com>
```

this is my source list:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian main upstream import
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest testing main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/security testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/multimedia testing main non-freee
```

Comment: It could be that the typo `non-freee` instead of `non-free` in the last line of the source.list causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Run `apt-get update` and try again. It could happen that the signatures are wrong during an update of the repository.

Comment: That's what Elemental did, or not?

Comment: @donquixote As I wrote, it can happen that this error occurs only temporary, so re-running `apt-get update` after some time (as soon as the whole repository is updated) can fix it.

Comment: Ok, worth a try :)
I had the same thing and had to change my sources.list to fix it. Still a bit mysterious, but seems ok now. And now my sources.list is the same as Elemental has. EDIT: "Mysterious" as in too nebulous to make this an "answer".